# Fatal error: Call to a member function isLoggedIn() on a non-object

Tags: php

I ran to problem which seems to be unable to solve by me, tried to use google but did not get any good answers there, so i'm hoping you guys can help me here!

Heres a tiny piece of code what can be issue, but what is, i have no idea.

```
    <?php
include('.//bin/php/ipbwi/ipbwi.inc.php');
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $username = isset($_POST['ips_username']);
    $password = isset($_POST['ips_password']);
    if($username && $password) {
        $ipbwi->member->login($_POST['ips_username'], $_POST['ips_password'], false, false);
    }
}
$user = $ipbwi->member;
if($user->isLoggedIn()) {
    $user = $user->info();
} else {
    $user = null;
}
?>
```

Comment: `$user` is not an object of a class

Comment: `$user = $ipbwi->member; var_dump($user);` and show us what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
include('.//bin/php/ipbwi/ipbwi.inc.php');
```

to this:

```
include('../bin/php/ipbwi/ipbwi.inc.php');
```

Comment: now got more errors when trying ('../bin/php/ipbwi/ipbwi.inc.php');
Warning: include(../bin/php/ipbwi/ipbwi.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/mikk2912/public_html/index.php on line 2

Warning: include(../bin/php/ipbwi/ipbwi.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/mikk2912/public_html/index.php on line 2

Warning: include(): Failed opening '../bin/php/ipbwi/ipbwi.inc.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php54/lib/php') in /home1/mikk2912/public_html/index.php on line 2

Comment: sry u set full path that line.